# Ajax only posting half of the data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to post data with jQuery ajax but its only posting half of the data to the next page.

I can see the all the data is being sent to the next page in the chrome developer tools but the response from the page its sending to is unsuccessful.

Here is my JS code:

```
    var id = $(this).parents('tr').attr('data-id');
        var time = $('#time').val();
        var mon = $('#mon').val();
        var tue = $('#tue').val();
        var wed = $('#wed').val();
        var thu = $('#thu').val();
        var fri = $('#fri').val();
        var sat = $('#sat').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "update.php",
        data: {
             "id": id,
             "time": time,
             "mon": mon,
             "tue": tue,
             "wed": wed,
             "thu": thu,
             "fri": fri,
             "sat": sat
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response)
        {
            if(!response.error) {
                console.log(response.msg);
            } else {
                console.log(response.msg);
            }
        }
    });
```

and the update.php code:

```
if ( isset($_POST) ) {

    if( isset($_POST['id'] ) && $_POST['id'] > 0 && !$error) {
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $error = false;
    } else {
        $error = true;
    }

    if( isset($_POST['time'] ) && $_POST['time'] > 0 && !$error) {
        $time = $_POST['time'];
        $error = false;
    } else {
        $error = true;
    }

    if( isset($_POST['mon'] ) && $_POST['mon'] > 0 && !$error) {
        $mon = $_POST['mon'];
        $error = false;
    } else {
        $error = true;
    }

    if( isset($_POST['tue'] ) && $_POST['tue'] > 0 && !$error) {
        $tue = $_POST['tue'];
        $error = false;
    } else {
        $error = true;
    }

    if( isset($_POST['wed'] ) && $_POST['wed'] > 0 && !$error) {
        $wed = $_POST['wed'];
        $error = false;
    } else {
        $error = true;
    }

    if( isset($_POST['thu'] ) && $_POST['thu'] > 0 && !$error) {
        $thu = $_POST['thu'];
        $error = false;
    } else {
        $error = true;
    }

    if( isset($_POST['fri'] ) && $_POST['fri'] > 0 && !$error) {
        $fri = $_POST['fri'];
        $error = false;
    } else {
        $error = true;
    }

    if( isset($_POST['sat'] ) && $_POST['sat'] > 0 && !$error) {
        $sat = $_POST['sat'];
        $error = false;
    } else {
        $error = true;
    }

    if( !$error ) {
        $query = "UPDATE table
                  SET time      = '$time',
                      monday    = '$mon',
                      tuesday   = '$tue',
                      wednesday = '$wed',
                      thursday  = '$thu',
                      friday    = '$fri',
                      saturday  = '$sat'
                  WHERE scheduleID = '$id'";

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die("database error:". 
mysqli_error($conn));
        $msg = array('error' => $error, 'msg' => 'Success! updation in mysql');
    } else {
        $msg = array('error' => $error, 'msg' => 'Failed! updation in mysql');
    }
}

echo json_encode($msg);
```

and the html (using the editable table from the Metronic admin theme)

```
<div class="table-toolbar">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button id="sample_editable_1_new" class="btn green"> Add New
                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" id="sample_editable_1">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Monday</th>
        <th>Tuesday</th>
        <th>Wednesday</th>
        <th>Thursday</th>
        <th>Friday</th>
        <th>Saturday</th>
        <th>Edit</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr data-id="5">
        <td class="time">05:30</td>
        <td class="mon">Program Name</td>
        <td class="tue">Program Name</td>
        <td class="wed">Program Name</td>
        <td class="thu">Program Name</td>
        <td class="fri">Program Name</td>
        <td class="sat"></td>
        <td>
            <a class="edit" href="javascript:;"> Edit </a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a class="delete" href="javascript:;"> Delete </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Only the "id" and the "time" is received at the update.php file.

I've tried adding the contentType and JSON stringify but then none of the data is received at update.php.

What am I doing wrong? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Try and `print_r($_POST)` in update.php file. That will give an insight to what is happening and also tells what data was sent

Comment: What kind of data type you are using for those input (#mon to #sat)? If they are not integer or double then "$_POST['wed'] > 0" will be failed logically.

Comment: Does the server respond with a content-length in the header? Is there server-side caching?

Comment: Share your HTML also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try

```
<?php 

if ( isset($_POST) ) {

    extract($_POST);

    if ( !isset($id) || empty($id) ) {
        echo json_encode(array('error' => true, 'msg' => 'missing [id]'));exit;
    }

    if ( !isset($time) || empty($time) ) {
        echo json_encode(array('error' => true, 'msg' => 'missing [time]'));exit;
    }

    if ( !isset($mon) || empty($mon) ) {
        echo json_encode(array('error' => true, 'msg' => 'missing [mon]'));exit;
    }

    if ( !isset($tue) || empty($tue) ) {
        echo json_encode(array('error' => true, 'msg' => 'missing [tue]'));exit;
    }

    if ( !isset($wed) || empty($wed) ) {
        echo json_encode(array('error' => true, 'msg' => 'missing [wed]'));exit;
    }

    if ( !isset($thu) || empty($thu) ) {
        echo json_encode(array('error' => true, 'msg' => 'missing [thu]'));exit;
    }

    if ( !isset($fri) || empty($fri) ) {
        echo json_encode(array('error' => true, 'msg' => 'missing [fri]'));exit;
    }

    if ( !isset($sat) || empty($sat) ) {
        echo json_encode(array('error' => true, 'msg' => 'missing [sat]'));exit;
    }

    $query = "UPDATE table
              SET time      = '$time',
                  monday    = '$mon',
                  tuesday   = '$tue',
                  wednesday = '$wed',
                  thursday  = '$thu',
                  friday    = '$fri',
                  saturday  = '$sat'
              WHERE scheduleID = '$id'";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn));

    echo json_encode(array('error' => false, 'msg' => 'Update success'));exit;
}else{
    echo json_encode(array('error' => true, 'msg' => 'missing [POST]data'));exit;
}

?>
```

... to catch the exact error after you submit your data.

And as **tima_t** already said, check the values of your **#mon**, **#tue** ... inputs.

Answer (score 0):

P Parsons, Could you provide and the html template for the code.
I think that it is possible to mon, tue, wed to be empty at the moment when you assign the value. Maybe the elements with id #mon, #tue ... #sun do not have the 'value property.'

Comment: I checked the values in the sources window of chrome's developer tools and they are stored in the js code and all the values are stored in the ajax data. The values are in the post headers according to the network window in the developer tools.I am using the editable datatable of the Metronic Admin theme on themeforest